# Auto pull Scripts folder in a Raspberry

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, bitbucket

I have a folder called RaspberryScripts in my computer. I have GIT installed on both, computer and raspberry and I'm using Bitbucket as Git server.

Sometimes I modify any script inside that folder on my computer and commit and push the changes to the Bitbucket server.

I've been searching **how to make Raspberry automatically pull the changes every time the server is updated**. I've found some tutorials about doing this for the public_html but I'm not sure if that will work in my situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Git hooks must help you with your task - [Manage Bitbucket hooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks)